# Cannot type '|' (pipe) symbol on terminal in Raspberry Pi Lite OS

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I want to use the pipe command, but whenever I type a pipe symbol (`|`) on the terminal, it displays a tilde (`~`) instead. There are also several other characters for which this happens. I'm using a Raspberry Pi Zero W. Why does this happen and how can I type the pipe symbol?

Comment: Check your keyboard layout setting.

Comment: Try other keys with `Shift` and perhaps even `Alt Gr` until you find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have this problem because the Raspberry Pi is configured with the United Kingdom layout by default, and I suppose the keyboard you are using is an American one. You can change your layout settings using mainly two different methods :

- Enter the command `sudo raspi-config` then go to "Localisation Options", then "Keyboard" and then you can choose the us keyboard layout.
- If that doesn't work, you can also type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. The keyboard model isn't very important, however make sure that you choose "English (US)" for the country of origin and then "English (US)" for the layout. You can keep the default settings for everything else.

You can see the differences between the US and UK keyboard layouts on this page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` worked for me but I had to reboot for it to take effect. OS: dietpi, HW: Rasp pi zero W